# excel, ms-query and datetime parameter to query ms sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameter-passing, excel-2010, ms-query

I'm trying to run a SQL-query in Excel 2010 to MS SQL-Server 2008 with one parameter in DATETIME format:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myCreateDate > ?
```

The column myCreateDate is DATETIME in MS SQL-Server.
The parameter comes from a cell in Excel.

What do I have to enter in the Excel-cell?
If I create the query in msquery directly, it writes

```
myCreateDate > {ts '2013-03-19 10:01:36'}
```

and it works. But I cannot get it work with a parameter.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To change the parameter just edit the query in Data>connections>. Change the date time to ? 
When you close you will be prompted to go pick an excel cell. Just enter the date in the cell in any format and it should work.